# How to run JavaScript code line-by-line in PhpStorm or WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to run my JavaScript code line by line in PhpStorm to debug it. How can I do this?

Please explain it for me.

Comment: You can use the browser debugger too if the scripts are required to debug on the client side.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start the JavaScript Debug session (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session) and, once breakpoint is hit, use Step Over to run it line-by-line

Comment: Page was deleted